# Ionic 1: Ionic list printing selected item value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've just started out using Ionic, I am trying to print the value of the selected list Item `{{ item.value }}` , however can't find any documentation that suggests how to do this.

Possibly an `ng-click="myFunction()"` would work here, but I am stuck as to where to start. I have it working with the Ionic Radio buttons. But I want the list to re-direct to another page on click, but still hold this value in the main controller.

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nicks_12/pen/qNQdrm?editors=1010) attempt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at first `ng-click="do"` will do absolutely nothing. It should be `ng-click="do()"`, and of course, you have to have a `function` called `do` in your `controller` to perform an `action`.

The 2nd. problem is: you're inside `ngRepeat`, it creates a *child* `$scope`, so you have to use the `Dot Rule`:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Then, you can do it:

```
ng-click="model.itemValue = item"
```

Check the forked <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBrGZK?editors=1010)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much. I was getting so confused, but it's very clear now. If I wanted only the value, not the JSON, I would do 'ng-click="model.itemValue = item.value'?

Comment: @nick_1002 yes. Can you check it as answer?

Comment: I'm glad that this has helped :)